# Two logic circuits controlled from two SPST switches?

Tags: switches

I have two low power 12 volt circuits (C1, C2) that operate relays. I want to control these with two SPST switches (S1, S2) in a Boolean manner: (S1 OR S2) for C1, and (NOT S2) for C2.

Can these circuits be wired in parallel off the same two switches, using relays for the logic gates as shown below?  Will there be any negative interactions between these logic circuits, or these and the relays that C1 and C2 themselves control?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the relay coils can be wires in parallel so each switch can be SPST and the electrical supply for the lights can also be in parallel,

You appear to be proposing this circuit, which will work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiIKkC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But two relays in parallel can be replaced with a relay that has more contacts.
it's usually cheaper this way.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP1kDv.png)</sup>

If the two lamps have the same power source you could also use the same relay in both circuits (so you only need two sinlge pole relays)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0JGQU.png)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can combine them — in fact, it's rather straightforward:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fl4KNs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Your question is not entirely clear about whether the 12V applies to the switches or the loads, so I've kept the diagram completely generic. The coils on the relays need to match whatever the switch power supply is in terms of voltage and AC vs DC. Note that SW1/RLY1 and SW2/RLY2 could also have entirely separate supplies if necessary.

You also didn't indicate whether C1 and C2 need to be isolated from each other, so just to be safe, I kept them separate.

RLY1 only needs to be SPST, but RLY2 needs to be DPDT. Of course, you could use DPDT in both positions and just ignore the extra contacts. And if C1 and C2 don't need to be isolated from each other, then RLY2 can be SPDT.